# Can I keep 5 x 8ml liquid in its original package to carry in my hand luggage?

Tags: uk, airport-security, hand-luggage, lhr

While passing through the security checks at Heathrow Airport, passengers are requested to put their liquid into plastic bags provided. I want to carry the below package (5 x 8ml bottles of cologne) in my hand luggage.

Is it possible to keep the original package, or shall I remove the package?

[image: cologne]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting them in checked package is simpler and safer.

In theory you cannot leave such bottles on the original packages, but if you do not have other liquids, you may interpret that the original packages is the *transparent bag*. Often you can pass the security check in similar cases: security staff can see the interior (and check which kind of liquid and size).

Personally, sometime I took liquids supplements on original package (very small bottles in carton package), and nobody ever complained. But I'm ready to trash away the small box. So this could be your plan B: try with original package, and be ready eventually to open the box. Personally I find that keeping the original package is simple for the custom on arrival.

You may notice that many people does security check in the wrong way. But do not worry, they will not put you in jail nor trash your item. You may need to do again the check with proper methods (so get ready also a correct plastic bag to put your items).

And BTW, your box could be seen as transparent and resealable bag. It is a valid interpretation (but never argue about this: if they tell you it is not valid, comply with they interpretation).

Note: if you buy such item at airport (duty free), things can be a lot simpler: you will have it in a sealed bag with some labels. Such sealed bag is recognized in many airports (in case of transfer flights), without worrying about packing and dimensions.

Comment: Giacomo can you please check your answer, I suspect some wrong words slipped in.

Comment: "And BTW, your box could be seen as transparent and resealable bag. It is a valid interpretation" - perhaps you can argue that it's resealable, but there is absolutely no valid interpretation of that mostly opaque box as a transparent bag. That's not to say you won't get through with them, I've regularly taken liquids through without following the rule about the bag and very rarely had any trouble as long as the quantity was small. But that's not a sign of the box complying with the regulations.

Comment: I tried my luck, but failed. :) I resealed the original packaging after the security check, it was still OK.

Answer (score 4):

No, security requires the bottles be removed from the original packaging.

The [Heathrow.com page on Security](https://www.heathrow.com/departures/security-and-baggage/hand-baggage-and-liquids#Liquids100mlrule) contains this text about carrying liquids with you into the cabin:

***Liquids - 100 ml rule***

*Only limited quantities of liquids may be carried through airport security into the departure lounge. This includes bottled drinks, suntan lotion, fragrances, cosmetics, toiletries and all frozen liquids.*

*The following restrictions apply to all liquids, creams, gels, pastes and aerosols taken through security control:*

- *Liquids may only be carried in containers holding 100ml or less.*
- *They must be carried separately in a single bag which is:*

  - *Transparent and resealable*
  - *No larger than 20cm x 20cm (8in x 8in)*
  - *Able to close properly with all the items inside.*
- *At security control, place the bag in the tray with your other items.*
- *Liquids in containers over 100ml will not be permitted through security – please pack them in your hold baggage instead.*